# Сумма всех простых чисел меньше заданного рекурсивно

Tags: python, рекурсия

нужно мне решить одну простую задачку, но додуматься не могу.
Вот что написал сейчас:

```
def IsPrime(n):
    if n % 2 == 0:
        return n == 2
    d = 3
    while d * d <= n and n % d != 0:
        d += 2
    return d * d > n

def pi(x):
    sum = 0
    if x > 1:
        if IsPrime(x - 1):
            sum += pi(x-1)
            print (x)
            return x
        else:
            pi(x-1)
            return 0
    else:
        return sum

print(pi(10))
```

задача вывести сумму всех простых чисел меньше 10, для этого сделал функцию проверки и рекурсивную pi. Внутри вызываю с параметром на 1 меньше, но как посчитать саму сумму не пойму.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

зачем так сложно то :)

```
def pi(x):
    return 2 if x == 2 else ((x if IsPrime(x) else 0) + pi(x - 1))
```

основные принципы:

1. выводим 2, если `x` равно 2, ну можно рекурсию и позже прервать - например выводить 0, если `x` равно 0
2. иначе если число простое - то прибавляем к результату функции с меньшим аргументом это число `x` иначе 0 (т.е. составные числа не учитываем)

P.S.

можно чуть-чуть упростить функцию:

```
def pi(x):
    return 2 if x == 2 else (x * int(IsPrime(x)) + pi(x - 1))
```

P.P.S.

а чтобы учесть все целые числа можно сделать так:

```
def pi(x):
    return 0 if x < 2 else (x * int(IsPrime(x)) + pi(x - 1))
```

Comment: Zhihar - аплодирую стоя... правда, у меня возникло чувство лёгкого дежавю: как ни зайду на SO - попадается на странице вопрос сделать что нибудь с примемением рекурсии...

Comment: `int(IsPrime(x))` в `int` переводить не обязательно

Answer (score 1):

```
def pi(x):
    sum = 0
    if x > 1:
        if IsPrime(x):
            sum += x
        return sum + pi(x - 1)
    else:
        return 0
```

Answer (score 0):

А зачем вам рекурсия?

```py
def pi(n):
    primes = [2]
    for i in range(3,n,2):
        is_prime = True
        for p in primes[:len(primes)//2]:
            if i % p == 0:
                is_prime = False
                break
        if is_prime:
            primes.append(i)
    return sum(primes)

print(pi(10000)) # 5736396
```